# when a mysql query is executed it shows a record multiple times although only single entry is present in database

Tags: php

When a mysql query is executed it shows a record multiple times although only single entry is present in database. Why is this happening?
Whenever I execute the query

```
SELECT  a.*, 
        b.CNTCT_ADD_ID  AS Cntct_Add_Id,
        c.PHONE_NBR_ID AS Cntct_nbr_Id, 
        d.OA_NM AS OaNm,
        e.HOUSE_NAME AS house,
        e.FLAT_NO AS flat,
        e.HOUSE_NO AS houseno,
        e.ADDRESS_LINE_1 AS Address1,
        e.ADDRESS_LINE_2 AS Address2,
        e.ADDRESS_LINE_3 AS Address3, 
        f.PHONE_NBR AS phneNO
FROM contact_add_phoneno a
LEFT JOIN contact_address b ON a.CNTCT_ADD_ID = b.CNTCT_ADD_ID  
LEFT JOIN contact_phones  c ON a.CNTCT_NBR_ID = c.PHONE_NBR_ID
LEFT JOIN org_accounts d ON a.OA_ID_ORIGINATED = d.OA_ID
LEFT JOIN address_mst e ON e.ADDRESS_ID = b.ADD_ID 
LEFT JOIN phone_nbr_mst f ON f.PHONE_NBR_ID =c.PHONE_NBR_ID
```

it displays same record more than 2 times.

Answer (score 5):

It's because of the join.  change `SELECT` TO `SELECT DISTINCT` to remove duplicate rows.

Comment: Keep in mind that the distinct keyword has a large impact on the performance of queries.